# use single hover script for a bunch of buttons, with a variable on mouseover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, hover

I'm trying to define a variable on a mouseover event.

The idea is that I can later use that variable to replace the DIV ID's, and "swap-image" pahts to create a generic mouseover script that I can use for a bunch of buttons.

So I don't have to use the same code over and over again and only swich out a few numbers.

Would this work? I tried something like this:

```
//define variable on mouseover

$("#world_map_8_button").mouseover(function() {
        var location = "#world_map_8";

    }); 


//use variable within script

   //mouse over/out swap image + 

$(location + "_button").hover(function() {
    $(location + "_button_jpg").attr("src", "img/buttons/map_buttons/world_map/world_map_8_button_over.jpg"); 
        }, function() {
            $(location + "_button_jpg").attr("src", "img/buttons/map_buttons/world_map/world_map_8_button.jpg"); 
        }); 
 });
```

This is some of the html code to help things clear up, all buttons are named the same way.

```
    <div id="world_map_8_button">
            <img id="world_map_8_button_jpg" src="img/buttons/map_buttons/world_map/world_map_8_button.jpg" width="41" height="41"  alt="" />
        </div>

    <div id="world_map_9_button">
            <img id="world_map_9_button_jpg" src="img/buttons/map_buttons/world_map/world_map_9_button.jpg" width="41" height="41"  alt="" />
        </div>


    <div id="world_map_10_button">
            <img id="world_map_10_button_jpg" src="img/buttons/map_buttons/world_map/world_map_10_button.jpg" width="41" height="41"  alt="" />
        </div>
```

if I declare the variable in the HOVER function it works (only for the mouseon though) but that doesn't make any sense and wouldn't be labour saving...

```
$("#world_map_8_button").hover(function() {

                var location = "#world_map_8";

    $((location + "_button_jpg")).attr("src", "img/buttons/map_buttons/world_map/world_map_8_button_over.jpg"); 
        },
        function() {
            $((location + "_button_jpg")).attr("src", "img/buttons/map_buttons/world_map/world_map_8_button.jpg"); 
        });
```

Comment: It will be better if you post your mark sample to help u better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good candidate for CSS. You could have one image with both the hover and normal images in, and then set the background offset when the mouse hovers. [W3Schools explains the technique well](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp)

To answer your question directly, however, you could try something like this:

```
$('[id$=_button]').hover(function() {
    $('#'+this.id+'_jpg').attr('src', 'img/buttons/map_buttons/world_map/' + this.id + '_over.jpg');
}, function () {
    $('#'+this.id+'_jpg').attr('src', 'img/buttons/map_buttons/world_map/' + this.id + '.jpg');
});
```

You would only have to put this on your page to take care of it all without having multiple scripts and global variable declarations.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at your code I think attribute [ends with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) selector `$=` will help you. You don't have to set any variable to do this, try this

```
$("[id$=_button]").hover(function() {
    $("#" + this.id + "_jpg").attr("src", "img/buttons/map_buttons/world_map/" + this.id + "_button_over.jpg"); 
        }, function() {
            $"#" + this.id + "_jpg").attr("src", "img/buttons/map_buttons/world_map/" + this.id + "_button.jpg"); 
        }); 
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

No that won't work. Use [jQuery's `.data();` method](http://api.jquery.com/data).